# Sharepoint 2010 - Pass "u" parameter to advanced search

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

The scenario - I am building a site to house a number of reports - thirty or so subsites under a main web for different report categories, and several libraries in each site, one for each separate report. In total, about 600 reports (libraries) across the thirty report categories (sites).  This design has been decided on, and cannot change.

I plan/want to have a single advanced search page to search all the reports, using various custom metadata columns.  That bit's easy, I can do that out of the box.

One of the most important search criteria is which report on which to search, of which, as I mentioned, there are many.  The dictate is to make the report type added "invisibly" - they will select the report category, then the report type, and THEN get presented with the search page.  The search should "know" which report is being searched on.

Scope selection is not a viable option, as there's too many libraries, and more will be added as new reports are created.

Now, I can get the results I want in the results if I add the "u" parameter to the URL as in;

```
results.aspx?k="RunDate=1/23/13"&U=http://site/report_type/library"
```

(address left unescaped for clarity)

My challenge is finding a way to feed that parameter TO the advanced search, and get it to tack it on to the end of its generated query.

I'm confident it can be done with only a little fidgeting to the webpart, but I need a bit of a shove in the right direction.

Or, as always, if y'all have a more brillianter idea, I could do that.

Now, I have a second issue where the different reports have their own varying set of metadata columns, and they only want the RIGHT ones to show up for each report, but one crisis at a time.

EDIT - upon further research, it seems I can't extend the advanced search webpart, as it's a sealed type.  Has anyone either a way around that, or have a third-party advanced search page that I CAN crack into?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a solution to this issue by overriding the JavaScript function NavigateTo(url) which is responsible for the redirect. My solution can be found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100267/sharepoint-2010-advanced-search-appened-to-keyword-query/100371#100371)

Comment: Yep, that should do it, plus another function to geenerate the path.

But whereabouts in the Sharepoint page can I drop in that overridden function so it'll supplant the one that gets autogenerated when the SP page is dynamically built?

Comment: I used a content editor that I have placed on each search page

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually asking about is a contextual search box, as the `u` parameter resembles the *contextual search scope*.

I'm not sure that the standard search box can be configured the way you want it to, so it always adds the query string `u=<current url>`. I think you will have to resort to some (even if simple) code.

An example you can find here: [Create a SharePoint Contextual Search Box in a Content Editor Web Part](http://joshmccarty.com/2010/11/create-a-sharepoint-contextual-search-box-in-a-content-editor-web-part/). 
Of course you could do the same thing with server side code, but as you only want to add a querytring parameter, JavaScript should be enough.

Comment: This is precariously close, but the problem is I need to use the advanced search to generate my query, not a simple search box.  I've found any number of ways to extend or alter the basic search box, but after more research, I've discovered the advanced search webpart is a sealed type, so I can't even get into it to diddle with it.

Is there an event I can check for after Advanced generates the new URL, and before the redirect is done? That muight be a way for me to tack my parameter on.